# attach python image from discord discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am programming a bot in Python that what I should do is upload an image from Discord and post a link, but it is not working for me, I don't know where the error could be.

This is the bot:

[image]

My code in Python:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Client
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_choice, create_option
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
####

bot = Client()

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=['!','/','.'], description="ayuda bot") #Comando

bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help

slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)
@slash.slash(
    name="imgur", description="imgur",
    options=[
        create_option(
                name="image",
                description="Attach an Image",
                required=True,
                option_type=11, #Attachment
                
        )])


async def _imgur(ctx:SlashContext, image: discord.Attachment):
   
    print(image)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("BOTS ready")

bot.run("")
```

When uploading the photo, it generates a code, and the URL does not appear
[image]

Can someone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: How is the posted code related to your question?

Comment: already updated it

Answer (score 0):

Your imports suggest that you are using the [legacy version of interactions.py](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/legacy-v3/) which [does not support](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/legacy-v3/discord_slash.model.html?highlight=ApplicationCommandOptionType#discord_slash.model.SlashCommandOptionType) `option_type=11` for attachments. The Discord API appears to be accepting `option_type=11`, but your code does not and is defaulting to a string. Try updating your version with `pip install -U discord-py-interactions` and refactoring your code for the new version by following the [latest guide here](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).

Also, attachments on Discord are typically backed by a resource link on Discord's content delivery network (CDN). It looks like you're sending the attachment object, which is just printing the attachment ID. Try sending the [attachment URL](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=attachment#discord.Attachment.url) instead.

```py
await ctx.send(f"{image.url}")
```

Comment: get an error in the console, how do I solve it? i.imgur.com/SPZQrDP.png

Comment: Can show more in your code about what imports you are using? I suspect you are using the legacy version of [discord-interactions](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/legacy-v3/) which [does not support](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/legacy-v3/discord_slash.model.html?highlight=ApplicationCommandOptionType#discord_slash.model.SlashCommandOptionType) `option_type=11` for attachments. You will probably want to use the [latest version of interactions.py](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to refactor your code for attachments.

Comment: I have already put in the posts the complete code that I am using

Comment: Your import statements confirm my suspicions. You are using the legacy version of `interactions.py`. Try updating your version with `pip install -U discord-py-interactions` and refactoring your code for the new version by following the [latest guide here](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).